# who first receive sms broadcast if the two have the same right

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I meet a problem: for example, i have two apps A and B,every one can receive SMS broadcast

```
   <receiver android:name=".ReceiveSms" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

when i run the two apps, then i use another device send one SMS to the device which have apps

A and B.A or B first receive the SMS.

Is there some rule? the A and B have the same right.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you set a priority for your receivers, then they both essentially have the same priority, and there is no guaranteed order in which they'll run. If you need one to receive the broadcast before the other, you can adjust their priorities in the `<intent-filter>` tag, like so:

```
<intent-filter android:priority="999">
```

NB: The maximum  (practical) priority is 999. You can set it higher, but it will essentially equal a priority of 999. The minimum priority is -999.

[BroadcastReceiver Reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html)

Comment: i give the two  both android:priority="999".so i have the question,i donot know who is first

Comment: In that case, there is "no guaranteed order". To quote the docs, "receivers with the same priority will be run in an arbitrary order."

Comment: If you need one to run before the other, simply drop one of their priorities to 998.